# Only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I tried to use "range based for loop" and "lambdas" in my programs. Everything was fine in fact. My IDE didn't throw any error or warning at all. After "catkin_make", I see some warnings in my terminal which says:

```
/home/serhathp/catkin_ws/src/tcp_edu/src/trial_06.cpp:41:9: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
         }
         ^
```

and same for "range based for loop" method. How can I handle this issue? What version of compiler do I use in my system? I typed some code in my program related to this issue:

```
   if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
```

As an output, I gave C++98. Maybe this would be useful information I don't know. Probably related to this issue, I can't use "range based for loop" correctly if I run my program. (I can compile my program actually) It doesn't work like it should! Any relationship?
How can I change my compiler version in my system. I want it to be C++11 especially.  I'm kind of confused and new at this environment. Any help?

UBUNTU 16.04 - Kinetic - Ros1. I use Visual Studio as IDE.

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370160/only-available-with--std=c++11-or--std=gnu++11/) by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2021-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your CMakeLists, try adding this line:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2021-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2021-01-24**:
I appreciate your answer. The answer was right before my eyes :D  I hadn't ever realized. Thank you so much.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(tcp_edu)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2021-01-24**:
No problem. Have fun!